# Open application in specific desktop (lxde)

Tags: lxde

how open application in specific desktop.

For example: 
i use Firefox, Banshee, Thunderbird.
Also i have a few desktops: ( 2 - named "Firefox", 4 - named "Mail", 5 - named "Music" )

How to open each application in certain desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to install and use `devilspie` and `gdevilspie` to set behaviors like you describe for windows that match certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean workspaces. You can do that through a script, please see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1128091.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. It links to a perfectly good script. Don't be a troll.

Comment: possibly whoever downvoted you did this because we try our best to include the relevant information here on this forum.  Feel free to copy and reedit the relevant information.  You can end with a "source" statement with a hyperlink back to ubuntuforums.

Comment: OK, I'll edit when I have a spare moment.